# Showing � characters in place of ' during submit through form in MySQL and also removing new line in text?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

I want submit text from text box in a form to a table in MYSQL which in turn show text in the post on website but there is a special quot ‘ in place of this ' which get converted into  Â

Please tell how to submit data with simple text without showing these characters

I have already used

```
urldecode ( string $str ) , str_replace ()
```

Here is my code

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(utf8_encode($_REQUEST['txtDescription'])));
```

Comment: Is your web page rendering in UTF-8 ?

Comment: both apostrophes on line 2 are different in ASCII try on this site http://textmechanic.com/ASCII-Hex-Unicode-Base64-Converter.html

Comment: In Firefox you can right-click the page and select 'View Page Info'

Comment: @idstam ya its saying so Encoding :UTF-8

Comment: At first remove the `utf8_encode()` from your code, then try again.

Comment: @hakre done ! still same

Comment: Well for the data that is already in your database, this won't change a thing. You need to convert and/or delete the existing data first. If you've done that, edit your question accordingly to the change you made in your code.

Comment: Everything needs to be in the same charset, so if you're planning on using UTF-8, then your database must be UTF-8, the PHP script must be saved as a UTF-8 file, and so must the HTML.  If anything is a different charset you'll find yourself in charset hell.  (If everything is in UTF-8 then you probably don't need to re-encode the string as UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

You should call SQL code

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

before DML or SELECT.

Then make sure your HTML is utf8 encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found answer of my question by doing deep study on net

Strange special characters shown in my question are shown due to meta tags

so when we add **UTF-8** meta then such type of characters are show so here is the solution

**Replace** below code on your webpage

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

**with**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing all code required to insert, retrieve and showing on webpage without showing any special characters

**During submit of text to MYSQL table using query use below code**

```
$description = $_REQUEST['txtDescription'];
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
```

**$description** variable will be used in SQL insert query

**During Retrieve and Showing of text from MYSQL table use below code**

```
<?php print(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $row['tDescription']));?>
```

And also follow the **1 Answer** above to show it properly